# How to use if condition using two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Can anyone help me on this? What I wanted to happen is that if the value exist in Table 1 (employee), it will then check Table 2 (mobilelist) if it also exist there. Here's the code:

```
 Private Sub TextBox_IDNumber_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox_IDNumber.LostFocus
    Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    Mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=12345;database=my_db"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim READER2 As MySqlDataReader
    Dim _isFound As Boolean = False
    Dim _isExist As Boolean = False
    Try
        Mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim empmr As String
        Dim empml As String
        Dim fn1 As String
        Dim fn2 As String
        Dim ln1 As String
        Dim ln2 As String
        empmr = "Select * from my_db.employee where IDNumber ='" & TextBox_IDNumber.Text & "'"
        empml = "Select * from my_db.mobilelist where IDNumber = '" & TextBox_IDNumber.Text & "' AND DateAssigned is not Null AND DateReturned is Null"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(empmr, Mysqlconn)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read()
            _isFound = True
            fn1 = READER.GetString("FirstName")
            ln1 = READER.GetString("LastName")
        End While

        If _isFound Then
            TextBox_FirstName.Text = fn1
            TextBox_LastName.Text = ln1

        ElseIf Not _isExist Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Not Found in Master Data")
            TextBox_IDNumber.Clear()
            TextBox_FirstName.Clear()
            TextBox_LastName.Clear()
            TextBox_IDNumber.Focus()
        End If

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error!")
    Finally
        Mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the second query exactly? By the way, regarding the first query you should read about `Parameters` to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: In the second query, it would check if the user (IDNumber) exist there since the table MobileList holds records of users issued with mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the appropriate **Primary Key** and **Foreign Key** relationship between the tables **Employee** and **MobileList** you use this query to find records on the **MobileList** table for an employee:

```
Dim myQuery as string
myQuery = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, MobileNumber 
           FROM Employee 
           JOIN MobileList
           ON Employee.IDNumber=MobileList.IDNumber   
           WHERE Employee.IDNumber=@ID"
```

**Note:** You should rename the **IDNumber** column on the **MobileList** to avoid confusion.

You should also improve your access to the database with the `Using` statement and take advantage of **Parameters** to prevent SQL injection:

```
Using myConn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
     myConn.Open()
     Using myCmd As New SqlCommand(myQuery, myConn)
         myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "Your ID value")
         Using myReader As SqlDataReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
             If myReader.HasRows Then
                 'There are mobile numbers issued to that ID'
                 Do While myReader.Read()
                     'Iterate through all existing records'
                 Loop
             Else
                 'There are no mobile numbers issued to that ID'
             End If
         End Using
     End Using
 End Using
```

Keep in mind that this gives you the mobile numbers for a particular employee, it doesn't tell you if a particular employee exists.